# Weird transform behavior with Images in WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, image, listview, rotatetransform, transformgroup

I've got a DataGrid with multiple columns.  In one of the inner columns, I am displaying an image.  This image needs to be rotated, so I used a `TransformGroup` to scale and rotate the image as needed.

If I do no rotate, using the following XAML, the image appears normally.  As I change the width of the image column, the image scales as expected.  It stays within the bounds of its column:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Image" Width="200" x:Name="image_column">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Margin="5">
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Now if I attempt to rotate the image as necessary within the image column, things get weird.  The column is still tied to the non-rotated image width, and the row height is tied to the non-rotated image height.  The image also intrudes on its left neighbor's space.  This is one variant of XAML that I have tried:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Image" Width="200" x:Name="image_column">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Margin="5">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8" />
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterX="0" CenterY="0" />
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=image_column, Path=Width}" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The TranslateTransform above is a complete hack to at least make the right edge of the image line up with the right edge of its column.

I've tried to add a Viewbox, thinking that the it would scale the way I want it to, with the rotated the image inside of it, but that didn't work.

Can anyone tell me what I am fundamentally missing here, and offer hints on how I can approach a solution?  The only idea I have at this point is to rotate the image and save to disk before display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [`LayoutTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) property instead of `RenderTransform`.

```
<Image.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"/>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Image.LayoutTransform>
```

As the column width is fixed, the ScaleTransform seems to be redundant.

```
<Image.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
</Image.LayoutTransform>
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'm getting an exception that I'm going to look into -- "Layout measurement override of element 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' should not return NaN values as its DesiredSize."

Comment: I've tried to temporarily work around this issue by setting the Min/Max Height/Width for the Image element, but still reports NaN for its DesiredSize.

Comment: As the column width is fixed anyway, you might drop the ScaleTransform.

Comment: I dropped both, actually.  The XAML I'm using now doesn't hardcode the column width.  But that was the problem, thanks!  I just changed it and now everything works.  :)